# How can I programmaticaly add a free running counter to a simulink model?

Tags: matlab, simulink

How can I add a Free-Running Counter to a Simulink model using a matlab script?
If we use:

```
add_block('built-in/Counter Free-Running','mySystem/Counter')
```

we get an error:

```
There is no block named 'built-in/Counter Free-Running'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Counter Blocks cannot be accessed via `'built-in'`. This block, and other blocks on the Sources pallete on the Block Library should be accessed from `simulink/Sources/`, so in this case the correct name is `'simulink/Sources/Counter Free-Running'`. For example:

```
add_block('simulink/Sources/Counter Free-Running','mySystem/Counter')
```